# CakePHP Access Multiple Database Table from a Model

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.x

There are several database tables setup :

1) Fruit
2) Vege
3) Drink

I am able to access these database tables in a CONTROLLER using this line below. With this line, I am able to access these other tables.

```
public $uses = array('Get', 'Fruit', 'Vege', 'Drink');
```

My problem is when trying to access them in a MODEL. When I try this code below, an error occurs.

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Get extends AppModel {



        public function getHistory( $limit ) {


        $searchLimit = $limit;


        $raw = $this->Fruit->find('all')
```

An error occurs at the line '$this->Fruit'.

*Call to a member function find() on a non-object...*

Any ideas how to call multiple database tables in a single MODEL ?

Answer (score 0):

First you should read on model associations [Model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

Second, if that doesn't fit your needs (meaning there is no clear association between models, honestly I don't see connection between `Get` and `Fruit`) you can use `ClassRegistry`:

```
$Fruit = ClassRegistry::init('Fruit');
```

Before you can use `ClassRegistry` you must add this before class definition:

```
App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried 'ClassRegistry' and it didn't work. I am using the 'Get' method as a centralised way to obtain the fruits and other items.

Answer (score 0):

Associate model by `$belongsTo, $hasMany or what ever relation you want.`

than access by `$this->Fruit->find()`

Comment: Thanks. I read the '$hasMany' and other relation, but couldn't find a proper solution for it.

Comment: How you are calling getHistory() function and from which controller? If you are in GetsController then call getHistory() by '$this->Get->getHistory($limit)'

Answer (score 0):

As accessing all the database tables work perfectly in the CONTROLLER, I did this in the CONTROLLER instead of the MODEL. It seems much easier and straight forward to do this in CONTROLLER.

A private function is created in the CONTROLLER, and accessed by other functions using '$this->myPrivateFunctionName()'